# M1 Max MacBook Pro/Ventura 13.3.1 strange resolution issue which ONLY seems to affect those resolutions which push the menubar under the camera notch

Tags: mac, resolution, safari

If there's a more appropriate forum to ask this, please point me in its direction. The Mac is still under AppleCare but I can’t get to an Apple Store. I have posted this multiple places, but no responses to date. Is there some guru here who might be able to point me in the direction of a) the cause and b) the resolution (see what I did there…?)

Basically, the issue is this (if you need clarification on anything, please ask).

The other day - about a fortnight ago - I noticed that the screen resolution had dropped from the default to 1496 x 967 (the resolution below). No idea why, but I could’ve done it accidentally. Found that I couldn’t put it back to default in icon view (it was greyed out) so switched to resolution list view.  Put it back to default that way.

Now I find that all windows have a black bar at the top (ie they don’t stretch to the top of the screen) …

[image]

…and the ‘overlay’ (with the max/min buttons) is missing in Safari (but ONLY in Safari)

[image]

So, because I’m autistic and need to know things, I did some investigating. The following table shows the resolutions which display (ha!) the issue:

[image]

The ones that DO are those which push the menubar underneath the camera notch. I haven’t installed anything in ages, so it can’t be affected by something I’ve installed. I have 4 accounts: three I’ve had on the go for ages, the other I created specifically to test if it was account-specific (it isn’t). I have rebooted in safe mode (running in safe mode now).

Is this likely to be a hardware or software issue? What can I do to ascertain what might be causing the problem…?